# Loop through controls within different control user in c#

Tags: c#, loops, user-controls, foreach, controls

Ok so here is my problem:I have a form with 10 user control (they are all the same) and they each include 1 textbox, 1 combobox and 5 checkbox.

By default everything is disabled, but with another checkbox the user will enabled either the textbox or the combobox or all 5 checkboxes.

I could easly do it by doing something like

```
    ucPlayer1.name.Enabled = true;
    ucPlayer2.name.Enabled = true;
```

etc .. but it seems unnecessary

Before I wasn't using any usercontrol so I could do something like:

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox && c != null)
           ((TextBox)c).Enabled = true;
    }
```

but now, i'm stuck, I can't get a working loop, i tried something like:

```
    foreach(UserControl uc in Controls)
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. If it is usercontrol then call the same method recursively.

```
private void DoItRecursive(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if(c is UserControl)
            DoItRecursive(c);
        else if (c is TextBox)
            c.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
DoItRecursive(this);
```

Where `this` refers to `Form` typically.

Note: I've removed  `c != null` checking from your code because `is` keyword takes care of that. You don't need to, and casting `c` to `TextBox` is redundant.

Comment: It works perfectly!! I didn't even have to change anything!! thanks a lot :D

Comment: Also note this will work only when you have `UserControl`, If you use `Panel` or something like that this will fail. In that case you need to use `if(c.Controls.Count > 0)
            DoItRecursive(c);`